# No change in redux state causing useEffect to run every time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have been struggling to solve this from last 3 hours. I have a redux state saved in local storage. All I want is to display a welcome message when state is changed. So, I passed a dependancy array for that redux state in useEffect. But whenever, I am returning to the page having that welcome message(from menu), useeffect is triggering and showing up welcome message everytime. I am clueless WHY?

Here's the store

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import counterReducer from '../components/main/childCount'
import animalReducer from '../components/animal/animalType'

import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import {combineReducers} from "redux";
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const reducers = combineReducers({
  counter: counterReducer,
  animal: animalReducer,
})

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    middleware: [thunk]
});
```

Here's the dispatch:

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { changeAnimal } from './animalType'
import { reset } from '../main/childCount'

export default function Animal() {
  const count = useSelector((state) => state.counter.value);
  const Animal = useSelector((state) => state.animal.value);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div>
    <div className="container-fluid w-50 mt-5">
      <select
        className="form-select"
        aria-label="Default select example"
        defaultValue={Animal}
        onChange={(e) => dispatch(changeAnimal(e.target.value))}
      >
        <option value="Lion">Lion</option>
        <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
        <option value="Snake">Snake</option>
        <option value="Panda">Panda</option>
        <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
        <option value="Penguin">Penguin</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And Here's the welcome message:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export default function Child() {

  const count = useSelector((state) => state.counter.value)
  const Animal = useSelector((state) => state.animal.value);  

  useEffect(() => {
    toast.info('Welcome to my family, I am ' + Animal + ' Parent!', {
      position: "top-left"
    });
  }, [Animal]);

  return (
    <div className="border border-3 border-success m-5">
      <div className="badge text-bg-warning fs-5 m-4">{Animal} has {count} child</div>
      <ToastContainer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have an incorrect mental model for what the dependency array does. The effect in `useEffect` with an empty dependency array is run once when the component mounts.

The effect in a `useEffect` with a single dependency will run once when the component mounts, then again whenever that single dependency changes.

This is why you are always seeing the greeting. See example 1 here:

https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#examples-dependencieshttps://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#examples-dependencies